# Who earned the publicity badges from a particular question\answer

Tags: support, publicity-badges

All of a sudden, I got many, many upvotes on a [question and the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10753306/601179) I gave to that question.

[image: reputation log screen shot]

The post didn't have new activity lately, so I guess someone shared a link to that post.
Is there a way to know who it is?

<sub>And suggest him next time he announce my posts, to make sure I'm not capped long time ago... :)</sub>

---

**Update:**

Google helped me find [the article](http://jqueryplugins.info/2012/05/why-readyhandler-is-not-recommended/) that simply copy-pasted my full question, but there isn't a user-id in the link.

Anyway, I'm interested to know if there is a way to know a thing like that?

Comment: It doesn't appear anyone has been awarded a publicity badge for it... At least there's [no badge that was awarded](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer) to that question title in the past 24 hours.

Comment: It wasn't me :)

Answer (score 5):

If anyone had used one of the promotional links (with their user ID in it) the question would appear on the [list of users who recently won the Announcer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer).

I don't know how popular that blog is, but there is a direct link back to your question at the bottom of the page (mis-labeled "newest questions tagged jquery – Stack Overflow").

Comment: And if someone will get the announcer badge some day, can I know it?

Comment: @gdoron You don't get a notification when someone gets the badge from your question.  You'd have to go check the list.

Comment: But I don't know when he will get it, I won't check the list every couple of hours... Never mind I was just curious, not a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

No publicity badges where awarded for the question, probably who ever shared it used the canonical url and not the promotional url that includes their user id. That said, your question appeared in the [jQuery forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-ready-handler-in-not-recommended) (see last comment), so you probably got a few views from there...

Comment: Thanks for the detective work! Anyway, is there a way to know what I'm asking - who won the publicity badge from a particular q\a?